# can i use list comprehension way to conditionally update values in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I am appending rows to a data frame and have an id column thats needs to be unique based on existing values in the DataFrame.

For new rows I want to add an id.

Here is example starting data (row 2 and 3 newly added)

|  | name | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 65 |
| 1 | F | 33 |
| 2 | H | 0 |
| 3 | V | 0 |

There is no order to the data and the may previously assigned ids are not be sequential. I just want to start at highest id and increment from there.

|  | name | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 65 |
| 1 | F | 33 |
| 2 | H | 66 |
| 3 | V | 67 |

I have implemented that as follows

```
 max_id = df[id_field].max()

    for i in df.index:
        if df.at[i, id_field] == 0:
            max_id += 1
            df.at[i, id_field] = max_id
```

I had to do it like this because i could not update the `max_id` inside a comprehension. This doesn't feel very python like. Can I do this in a more elegant way? with lambdas or comprehensions?
thanks

Comment: do you have to use the existing `id` values? why not use the index of the DataFrame?

Comment: I would suggest something like `df[id_field] = np.where(df[id_field] != 0, df[id_field], df[id_field].max() + (df[id_field] == 0).cumsum())`

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?  It's simple and easy to understand.  It's not common to use comprehension in code where you're looking for the side effects rather than to build a list/dictionary/set.  You'll just confuse people.  I suppose you could do a lambda, but again, why?

Comment: @NickODell thanks - I have not come across `cumsum` before I'll read up on that

Comment: `Frank` - why: I am finding my way in python and my question is really `Can I do this in a more elegant way` - I'm happy that what I've written is clear and works but I want to understand better how to use the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case we may need to use `groupby` with `cumcount` to get the increase and `cummax` get the max

```
x = df.id.ne(0).cumsum()
df.loc[df.id==0,'id'] = df.id.cummax() + x.groupby(x).cumcount()
df
Out[561]: 
  name  id
0    A  65
1    F  33
2    H  66
3    V  67
```

Comment: thank you - I was not aware of `cumsum` etc I will read up on that and come back to vote/accept

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea using [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
# identify values to replace
m = df['id'].eq(0)
# compute a factor and add the max + 1 
df.loc[m, 'id'] = df.loc[m, 'name'].factorize()[0]+df['id'].max()+1
```

Or using [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
# identify values to replace
m = df['id'].eq(0)
# replace by max + cumsum of boolean
df.loc[m, 'id'] = df['id'].max()+m.cumsum()
```

output:

```
  name  id
0    A  65
1    F  33
2    H  66
3    V  67
```

Comment: thank you - I was not aware of `factorize` I will read up on that and come back to vote/accept

Comment: @JohnnieL `factorize`'s function is dedicated to perform this particular task of making a numeric index from arbitrary values, we're just tweaking it a bit here ;)

Comment: so i like `factorize` i can see a lot of use for that. Just to confirm this relies on `name` values being unique - if there are any dupes then I wont get `id`s of new rows to have a monotonic increasing values - correct?
So e.g. I have input data of `df = pd.DataFrame({'name':["A","F","V","H", "A", "H"], 'id':[65,33,0,0,0,0]})` and it all goes wonky. Thats fine I just want to understand. Thank you for this

Comment: With this example it would produce 66, 67, 68, 67 for V, H, A, H. `factorize` reuses the previous id of H.

Answer (score 1):

The walrus operator will allow you to update `max_id` inside a comprehension:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':["A","F","H","V"], 'id':[65,33,0,0]})
print(df)

max_id = df['id'].max()
df.loc[df['id'] == 0, 'id'] = [(max_id := max_id + 1) for _ in range(sum(df['id']==0))]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  name  id
0    A  65
1    F  33
2    H   0
3    V   0
  name  id
0    A  65
1    F  33
2    H  66
3    V  67
```

Comment: thank you - I was not aware of the walrus, I will read up on that and come back to vote/accept